# Filtrar filas por intervalo de fechas con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo un problema con mi código.
En teoría el código debería buscar las filas que se encuentren en un intervalo de fechas y que su título se repita al menos 3 veces en ese intervalo.
La fechas se encuentran en la columna `created_on`.
Estoy tratando de hacerlo con `.loc`, pero me devuelve la matriz vacía.
Les dejaré parte del csv y el código.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

custom_event = pd.read_csv('schedule_custom_event.csv')
```

Este es el csv de ejemplo:

```
id,start,end,title,description,created_on,updated_on,end_recurring_period,color_event,es_actividad_principal,puntualizada,extra_plan,participantes,dirigentes,calendar_id,categoria_id,creator_id,organismo_id,rule_id,tipo_actividad_id,es_actividad_control,es_reunion,estrategia_id,dirigentes_internos_id,cumplir_ac,posponer_ac
709,2022-07-13 13:00:00+00,2022-07-13 21:00:00+00,Control de gestión en  la  aplicación de la Política de Cuadros en el MES,,2022-03-16 17:53:58.588873+00,2022-06-08 14:40:22.345014+00,,,false,true,false,,,1,,142,,,,false,false,2,,false,false
1199,2022-04-04 07:00:00+00,2022-04-14 22:00:00+00,Recorrido por las universidades para controlar aseguramientos del inicio del curso académico,,2022-04-07 16:18:29.204838+00,2022-04-07 16:18:29.204857+00,,,false,false,false,,,1,,66,,,,false,false,2,,false,false
34,2022-03-01 15:00:00+00,2022-03-01 16:00:00+00,Atención a delegacion de Angola,,2022-02-24 16:19:20.178695+00,2022-02-24 16:19:20.178717+00,,,false,false,false,Delegacion Angola,,1,,18,,,,false,true,4,65,false,false
1627,2022-07-19 12:00:00+00,2022-07-19 21:30:00+00,Entrega por las  entidades a la Dirección de Cuadros del Informe al Seguimiento a la evaluación de Cuadros 2021 (Anexo ),,2022-06-13 13:49:25.280646+00,2022-06-13 13:49:25.280664+00,,,false,true,false,,,1,,142,,,,false,false,2,24,false,false
1664,2022-04-15 14:00:00+00,2022-04-15 05:00:00+00,Entrega del Informe final del CIE  a la AP de Artemisa,,2022-06-13 18:08:03.888523+00,2022-06-13 18:08:03.88854+00,,,false,false,false,,Contralora General,1,,150,,,,false,false,2,,false,false
1702,2022-09-01 14:00:00+00,2022-09-30 21:10:00+00,"Realización de los Talleres Provinciales de Auditoría, Control y Supervisión. Según plan particular) ",,2022-06-13 18:37:55.333767+00,2022-06-13 18:37:55.333785+00,,,false,false,false,,Contralora general,1,,150,,,,false,false,2,,false,false
2311,2022-10-20 10:00:00+00,2022-10-20 12:00:00+00,Videoconferencia para Defensa del TS en Gestión de la Innovación Agraria del Centro Rector ULT.,,2022-09-16 14:50:52.987677+00,2022-10-14 17:48:31.797403+00,,,false,false,false,Minag,,1,,35,,,,false,false,1,5,false,false
1747,2022-06-18 05:10:00+00,2022-06-18 08:30:00+00,Elaboración de la Resolución de Ingreso,,2022-06-18 18:01:38.691183+00,2022-06-18 18:01:38.691242+00,,,true,false,false,Instituciones de educación superior,,1,,46,,,,false,false,2,5,false,false
1785,2022-09-20 14:00:00+00,2022-09-20 21:00:00+00,Visita de Control a la UIJ,,2022-06-20 16:18:58.182137+00,2022-06-20 16:18:58.182157+00,,,false,false,false,UIJ,,1,,18,,,,true,false,4,3,false,false
2157,2022-09-20 13:00:00+00,2022-09-20 16:00:00+00,Sesión de trabajo sobre estructura de interfaz de la UCf,,2022-08-26 15:59:21.715354+00,2022-09-23 16:28:31.074398+00,,,false,false,false,,,1,,8,,,,false,false,4,4,true,false
2005,2022-07-15 13:30:00+00,2022-07-15 15:00:00+00,Chequeo de las relaciones con Rusia,,2022-07-08 13:20:48.980465+00,2022-07-08 13:20:48.980483+00,,,false,true,false,Mincex,,1,,18,,,,false,false,4,3,false,false
2069,2022-11-23 14:00:00+00,2022-11-23 16:00:00+00,REUNION CON LOS TRABAJADORES DEL AREA DIEA,,2022-07-20 19:23:30.091712+00,2022-07-20 19:23:30.091731+00,,,false,false,false,,,1,,83,,,,false,true,3,15,false,false
1845,2022-07-13 13:00:00+00,2022-07-13 17:00:00+00,Participar en la constitución de la Empresa Interfaz de la Universidad de Oriente,,2022-06-23 17:29:31.282276+00,2022-06-24 21:05:19.630534+00,,,false,false,false,,,1,,10,,,,false,false,2,4,false,false
2121,2022-08-17 07:00:00+00,2022-08-17 08:00:00+00,Despacho  de venezuela en el MINCEX,,2022-07-22 19:10:53.756321+00,2022-07-22 19:10:53.75634+00,,,false,false,false,MINCEX,MINCEX,1,,191,,,,false,true,4,,false,false
1937,2022-07-05 12:00:00+00,2022-07-05 21:00:00+00,Visitas de trabajo a las ECTI polo cientifico Mayabeque.,,2022-07-01 14:24:50.972447+00,2022-07-01 18:14:18.981857+00,,,false,false,false,,,1,,317,,,,false,false,5,12,false,false
2196,2022-09-29 18:00:00+00,2022-09-29 21:00:00+00,"Chequeo del macroprograma Desarollo Humano, Equidad y Justicia Social (Proyecto Trabajo Digno) ",,2022-08-29 20:10:34.799541+00,2022-08-31 19:13:26.053575+00,,,false,false,false,,VPM JLPD,1,,156,,,,false,false,1,,false,false
2248,2022-09-02 23:00:00+00,2022-09-03 01:00:00+00,Reunión con los OACE para aseguramiento a la participación en el Congreso LASA-2022 y al Congreso 2023.,,2022-09-02 20:29:45.881489+00,2022-09-02 20:29:45.881507+00,,,true,false,false," MINCULT (UNEAC, AHS, Oficina del Historiador de  La Habana);   CC-PCC (DRI, Dpto. Ideológico, Dpto. Atención Social, ICAP e IHC); UJC (Centro de Estudio de la Juventud);  Instituto de información y Comunicación Social,  MINSAP; CITMA",,1,,44,,,,false,true,4,7,false,false
2301,2022-10-07 17:00:00+00,2022-10-07 20:00:00+00,Reunión de la Dirección del MES ,,2022-09-15 15:25:33.963518+00,2022-10-03 17:55:45.351402+00,,,false,false,false,,,1,,156,,,,false,false,2,65,false,false
1954,2022-09-12 13:00:00+00,2022-09-23 22:00:00+00,Evaluación externa de la Maestría en Ciencia de la Computación UO,Modalidad Virtual​,2022-07-06 16:48:56.160321+00,2022-10-04 17:17:02.994689+00,,,true,false,false,,,1,,169,,,,true,false,2,29,true,false
```

El objetivo es crear un rango de 1 mes y que se comportara de manera dinámica dependiendo de la fecha actual.

```
fechaFinal = dt.date.today()
fechaDelta = dt.timedelta (days = -30)
fechaInicio = fechaDelta + fechaFinal
fechaInicio = dt.date.strftime(fechaInicio, '%Y-%m-%d')
fechaFinal = dt.date.strftime(fechaFinal, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

En este punto estoy tratando de obtener los eventos ya realizados.
Lo que se pretende y no logro hacer es que sea excluida de la filtración futura.
La respuesta final sería que muestre en dataframe con las filas que estén en el intervalo y que sea diferente a los ya realizados.

```
custom_event_copy = custom_event.copy()
custom_event_copy = custom_event_copy.drop(['description', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'end_recurring_period', 'color_event', 'puntualizada', 'extra_plan', 'calendar_id', 'categoria_id', 'organismo_id', 'rule_id', 'tipo_actividad_id', 'cumplir_ac', 'posponer_ac'], 1)    # type: ignore
print('Actividades Simplificadas:\n', custom_event_copy)
print('\n')

#se crea el perfil del usuario con las actividades realizadas
act_realizadas = custom_event_copy.loc[custom_event_copy['creator_id'] == 66]
print('Actividades realizadas por el creador:\n', act_realizadas)
custom_event2 = dt.date.strftime(custom_event.loc['updated_on'], '%Y-%m-%d')

# Filtra datos entre 2 fechas
rango = custom_event.loc[(custom_event['updated_on'] >= fechaInicio) & (custom_event['updated_on'] < fechaFinal)]
print(rango)
```

Asumamos que estos sean los eventos creados por un usuario.
En la respuesta final, no se deben tomar los que el usuario haya creado

```
Actividades realizadas por el creador:
         id                   start                     end                                              title  es_actividad_principal  ... creator_id es_actividad_control  es_reunion  estrategia_id  dirigentes_internos_id
1     1199  2022-04-04 07:00:00+00  2022-04-14 22:00:00+00  Recorrido por las universidades para controlar...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
71    2008  2022-07-12 17:00:00+00  2022-07-12 19:00:00+00                                   Defensa doctoral                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
122    221  2022-09-19 13:00:00+00  2022-09-23 15:30:00+00  Taller virtual sobre perfeccionamiento de la E...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                    11.0   
253   2016  2022-07-04 12:00:00+00  2022-07-04 21:00:00+00  Entrega a la Dirección de Organización, Planif...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
276   2017  2022-07-07 19:00:00+00  2022-07-07 20:00:00+00                    Despacho con la rectora UCPEJV                    False  ...         66                False       False              2                    11.0    
...    ...                     ...                     ...                                                ...                     ...  ...        ...                  ...         ...            ...                     ...    
1961  1521  2022-05-27 07:00:00+00  2022-05-26 22:00:00+00  reunión de trabajo con el MIncex para especial...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
1962  1522  2022-05-30 07:00:00+00  2022-05-29 22:00:00+00  Audioconferencia para chequeo de programas de ...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
1963  1523  2022-05-30 11:00:00+00  2022-05-29 22:00:00+00  Atención a la UCMH para intercambio y colabora...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
1964  1524  2022-05-31 07:00:00+00  2022-05-30 22:00:00+00            Intercambio con BioCubaFarma  UNISIMON                    False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN    
1965  1525  2022-06-01 07:00:00+00  2022-06-01 10:00:00+00  Intercambio con los coordinadores de especiali...                   False  ...         66                False       False              2                     NaN
```

Esta pudiera ser una posible respuesta.
Téngase en cuenta que el código se esta rigiendo por la columna `created_on`.
Según el rango de fecha que se implementó anteriormente se estaría trabajando con el rango comprendido entre `20-10-2022` y la fecha de hoy. En resumen, para salir como posible respuesta, se deben cumplir 3 requisitos:

1. El evento no está creado por el usuario.
2. El evento se encuentra en el rango de fecha.
3. El evento debe repetirse al menos 3 veces en ese periodo.

```
     id                   start                     end                                              title  description  ... es_reunion estrategia_id  dirigentes_internos_id  cumplir_ac  posponer_ac
0  2444  2022-11-26 09:00:00+00  2022-11-26 09:00:00+01  Videoconferencia de la subcomisión nacional de...          NaN  ...      False             1                     5.0       False        False
1  1690  2022-11-28 14:00:00+00  2022-11-28 14:00:00+01  Firma y ratificación del Código de Ética por t...          NaN  ...      False             2                     NaN       False        False
2  2095  2022-12-15 13:00:00+00  2022-12-15 13:00:00+01  Visita de control confección y ejecución a los...          NaN  ...      False             2                    20.0       False        False
3  2031  2022-11-31 18:00:00+00  2022-11-31 18:00:00+01    Primer Ministro Chequeo de los Macroprogramas.           NaN  ...       True             2                     NaN       False        False
4  1870  2022-12-01 14:00:00+00  2022-12-01 14:00:00+01  Aseguramiento a las acciones de comunicación s...          NaN  ...      False             1                     5.0       False        False
```

Comment: Buenas @HeytalePazguato. Gracias por responder a mi publicacion. He editado el post con la informacion que ud pidio y con una explicacion un poco mas detallada. Espero que cumpla con lo que estuvo pidiendo. Estare agradecido con su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay unos pequeños problemas y por eso no funciona

1. Las columnas que desees comparar con fechas deben ser de tipo `datetime64`, una forma fácil de convertir todas las columnas que sean fecha al tipo correcto es utilizando el argumento `parse_dates` al leer el archivo `CSV`.
2. Al comparar una columna `datetime64` con una variable tipo `date` debes utilizar el accesor `dt.date` de la columna.
3. Debes estár seguro que hay filas que cumplen con los límites a comparar, ya que si lo hago con la fecha actual no me devuelve ningún resultado porque no los hay.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# Probando con fechas anteriores
fechaFinal = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days = -120)
fechaInicio = fechaFinal + dt.timedelta(days = -30)

# Leemos el archivo csv y convertimos las columnas created_on y updated_on a tipo datetime64 (Puedes agregar más columnas de ser necesario)
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', parse_dates = ['created_on', 'updated_on'])

# Creo un nuevo dataframe con solo dos columnas para no mostrar todas en el resultado
df1 = df[['id','updated_on']]

print(df1.loc[(df1['updated_on'].dt.date >= fechaInicio) & (df1['updated_on'].dt.date < fechaFinal)])
```

Esto imprime:

```
      id                       updated_on
10  2005 2022-07-08 13:20:48.980483+00:00
11  2069 2022-07-20 19:23:30.091731+00:00
12  1845 2022-06-24 21:05:19.630534+00:00
13  2121 2022-07-22 19:10:53.756340+00:00
14  1937 2022-07-01 18:14:18.981857+00:00
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion. es verdad que en los datos no existia esa coincidencia. el csv original tiene +2000 eventos, existiendo varias coincidencias. Le agradezco que me haya ayudado. Voy a poner en practica el codigo que mostro. Hasta ese punto lo que hace es estar en el rango. Que ideas podrias darme para que incluya despues de aparecer +3 veces en ese rango?

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta, quieres incluir 3 veces el rango dado? Por ejemplo, si el rango es 1 mes, mostrar un mes anterior, el mes del rango y un mes posterior? De igual forma esa sería una nueva pregunta, te recomendaría intentar resolverlo y si no puedes publica una nueva pregunta y con gusto te ayudamos.

Comment: @CasinerO, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Buenas @HeytalePazguato, le vuelvo agradecer por su ayuda, pero como puedo hacer para que la fecha de inicio siempre sea el primer dia del mes anterior. Por ej: fechaFinal = '2022-11-20' (hoy) y fechaInicio = '2022-10-1'