# ¿Cómo filtro los valores que se encuentran en un dataframe dadas dos fechas específicas?

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de datos que contiene los un recuento histórico de las tasas `TRM` a lo largo de los años, necesito encontrar todo los valores de las tasas que se encuentran entre el `30-04-2013` y el `31-05-2023`, tengo este código, pero solo me selecciona las fechas de los dos días que seleccioné cuando en realidad necesito también los valores de las fechas que se encuentran entre estas dos

```py
TRM=TRM[TRM.fecha.isin([datetime.date(2013,5,1), datetime.date(2023,6,1)])]
```

Comment: Quizás esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19070194/8179980) te ayude

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Filtrar filas por intervalo de fechas con pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/569476/filtrar-filas-por-intervalo-de-fechas-con-pandas)

Comment: ¿la fecha es el índice del DF?